# How can I understand that the remote party is stopped its video in pjsip

Tags: ios, video, pjsip

For an iOS application, I need to know that when the remote party is stopped its video for an existing call. Is there any API or event that triggered by pjsip library?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Method reference for `pjsua_call_vid_stream_is_running`:

> Determine if video stream for the specified call is currently running (i.e. has been created, started, and not being paused) for the specified direction.
> https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga23c0bd5a335b5fa0d02404cd03ca0d5e

Using the decoding direction we can check if the *incoming* video is running, but using the [`PJMEDIA_DIR_DECODING`](https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__TYPES.htm#gaf19d0dce3e3c99a3b9514726c28baa30) direction.

```
bool video_active = 
    pjsua_call_vid_stream_is_running(call_id, med_idx, PJMEDIA_DIR_DECODING);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Liam.
Does state PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED mean that video is stopped on remote peer?
If not, that is not an answer to my question.

What I expect to have is that there might be an event triggered by the pjsip library when remote peer's video is stopped (audio can continue).

Comment: Ah, sorry that wasn't clear on first read, apologies. Is `pjsua_call_vid_stream_is_running` what you're looking for on the "incoming" direction? https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga23c0bd5a335b5fa0d02404cd03ca0d5e

Comment: This api method can be used for my need. Thanks. I would like to accept your answer if you have a chance to add this solution to the main answer.

Comment: No problem, apologies for the confusion. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks again @Liam. Apart from this do you know that is there any way to get the last received RTP packets for remote peer's video streams?